# Passing filtered data from one component to another angular

Tags: angular, components, angular2-forms, angular-routing

I have `formgroup` where I take from and to destination and and i pass this object data to the service and check whether those routes busses are available but i am not able to subscribe this data returned in another component.

**home.component.ts**

```
  submit(value) {
const data = this.searchForm.value;
this.homeservice.getbus(data).subscribe((res) => {
    this.busfilter = res;
    console.log(this.busfilter);
     this.navigateToBusTicket();
},
() => {
});
}
 private navigateToBusTicket() {
  this.router.navigate(['busticket']);
}
```

}
**home.service.ts**

```
 getbus(data) {
return this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:3000/bus')
.map(
(response: Response) => {
    const items = response.json();
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (data.fromandto.from === items[i].from && data.fromandto.to === items[i].to) {
      // console.log(items);
      return items;
    }
  }
})
```

I want to subscribe this returned data in another component **busticket** how to do it?

Comment: Did you find the answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

For example in your `home.service.ts` you can use `EventEmitter` to emit event with data that you recived and than in other component you can handle that event - subscribe and process recived data. You can read more about component communication below.

- [Component events with EventEmitter and @Output in Angular 2+](https://toddmotto.com/component-events-event-emitter-output-angular-2)
- [Component Interaction Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)